# Anaconda3 2019.10 (64-bit) installation stuck at setting up the base environment

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

I have been using “Jupyter notebook” through anaconda for past few months. Recently I was having trouble in syncing my conda environment. I wanted to make some directory change as well. In order to do that I decided to uninstall the entire package and reinstall again . Since then, I have been trying to install but having an issue in the installation process. I am stuck at the “Setting up the base environment” stage for several hours.
[Please see the attached as followed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAt2z.png)

[It seems to be stuck at extracting python-3.7.4-h5263a28.conda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRxK4.png)

I would appreciate any possible help or solution to try on.

Thanks,
Rowzat

Comment: Any updates on the matter?